# Racket macros syntax matching with square brackets

Tags: scheme, racket

For some reason, running this line of code:

```
(TEST '("A"))
```

matches the syntax definition:

```
(define-syntax TEST
    (syntax-rules ()
       [(TEST [<table> <name>])
         (print "Should not be here")] ;This statement is executed
      [(TEST <table>) 
         (print "Should be here")] ;This should be executed but is not 
    ))
```

How is this possible? It doesn't make sense to me because the literal after TEST is just a single parameter. How can it match two pattern variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `'x` is just a reader abbreviation for `(quote x)`. For that reason, when you write `(TEST '("A"))`, it is exactly the same as writing `(TEST (quote ("A")))`. Therefore, it matches the first pattern, where `<table>` is bound to `quote` and `<name>` is bound to `("A")`.

This might be a little confusing, but keep in mind that macros operate entirely at compile-time. For that reason, `'("A")` is never evaluated to anything before being passed to the macro, it’s just handed off directly. The `syntax-rules` pattern-matching construct doesn’t care at all about the special meaning of `quote`, it just matches against the syntactic structure of lists and pairs, so you get the behavior you’ve discovered.

Depending on what you are actually trying to do, there are a couple ways to get the behavior you might want. If you want pattern-matching against runtime values, use `match`, not `syntax-rules`. If you really want a macro, but you want to be more specific about the kinds of things that will match, you might want to use `syntax-parse` instead of `syntax-rules`. Without more information, though, it’s hard to give a concrete suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

The reader turns `'("A")` into `(quote ("A"))`. This means that
`(TEST '("A"))` turns into `(TEST (quote ("A")))`.

This explains why the pattern `(TEST [<table> <name>])` matches. The subpattern `<table>` matches `quote` and `<name>` matches `("A")`.